# intermediate string processing with php

Tags: php, string

This is the string a want to process: `"very, very,  Random Stringby Random $10"`  The fixed strings are **$** and the last **by**. I do not know how many by's it will be before the last one.

I am looking for a way to unambiguously cut out the `"by Random"`("by" and the string/strings between $ sign) out of string.

I though I could do this by accessing the position of $ sign(I know there will always be $ sign in there at the right position) with `strpos function` and the position of the first "by" before $ sign. But I don't know how to tell it to look for the first "by" before the selected position, namely the $ sign. What approach do you recommend that I take?

Comment: You've provided a lot of words that don't describe what you want: Given your input string, what **exactly** do you expect / want back from it?

Comment: try [strripos()](http://php.net/strripos), it matches from the end of the string, e.g. `strripos('by', $str)` would find the last `by`.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I will do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) you can get the last portion of the string by combining that function with the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function like this:

```
$string = "very, very,  Random Stringby by by Random $10";
echo substr($string, strripos($string, 'by')); // by Random $10
```

Note that this PHP function is one of those requiring the haystack first, then the needle.

---

> NOTE: I was bitten by the order of the needle and haystack earlier today on this very function.

Comment: thank you. this seems optimal. Just a quick question before I dive into testing.  Since it goes in reverse...will it return the position of "b" or "y" of "by"?

Comment: It returns the position of the first character in the needle @krompir2